# Can spells function as feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats

I was looking through a necromancer class for pathfinder published by a [third party source](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/samurai-sheepdog/necromancer/) and I noticed a section that claims "At 3rd level, a necromancer gains Command Undead as a bonus feat." I was primarily wondering if this was possible, for a spell to function as a feat. If it is possible, how exactly does it work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Spells and Feats are separate things

A spell can't be a feat, and a feat can't be a spell. When the **class feature** *Command Undead* states you gain Command Undead as a bonus feat, it must be talking about the **feat** [Command Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead-final/), not the **spell** [Command Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/command-undead/).

Yes, there are 3 different things all called Command Undead. Context is required to know which is referred to. Since the class feature says you gain it as a bonus feat, it can only be referring to the feat of the same name.

Comment: @GreySage I think it would be nice to note that there are feats that grant specific spells as supernatural or spell-like abilities, usually with some other cost or restriction associated. The feat [Channeled Revival](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/channeled-revival/) is a good example of this.

Answer (score 5):

## No, Spells cannot function as feats (in general)

Specifically on Command Undead, there is both a [Command Undead Feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead-final/), as well as a [Command Undead Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/command-undead/); which can cause confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with this is that there is actually both a [spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/command-undead/) and [feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead-final/) with the exact same name. So in this case the class is actually granting you a feat.

Answer (score 4):

### You are mixing the feat with the spell of same name

Pathfinder has a feat called [Command Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead-final/), and also a spell called [Command Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/command-undead/). Sometimes they get mixed up, but the context should be enough to clarify which one the text is talking about. Here, it says:

> At 3rd level, a necromancer gains Command Undead as a bonus feat.

So, it's clear it is talking about the feat, [Command Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead-final/).

Comment: Do you mean 'Command' instead of 'Control'?